# can't wget from my nginx web server

Tags: nginx, networking, web, server, wget

I configured an nginx webserver.
I created index.html inside ~/www/public
and I configured nginx to go for this location
like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name webserver1.net;
    root /home/anasbarg/www;
    index index.html;
}
```

of course I added this line to /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.8.101 webserver1.net
```

obviously, 192.168.8.101 is my nginx web server IP

the problem is, when I try to open from firefox it works fine.
However when I try wget command to download the index page the output is this:

```
--2017-10-22 08:19:30--  http://webserver1.net/
Resolving webserver1.net (webserver1.net)... 192.168.8.101
Connecting to webserver1.net (webserver1.net)|192.168.8.101|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-22 08:19:30 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

so can any one explain it to me, I know that it's a basic question but I'm newbie :p so please I need your help.
thank you

Comment: Does wget also fail when you suppply the index.html at the end of the url?

Comment: Can you post the nginx log showing reason for 404? Also as @xxfelixxx mentioned what happens when you append `/index.html` to the url

Comment: @xxfelixxx yes it does fail when I supply the index.html at the end of the url

Comment: @tarun-lalwani I posted the log above. do you mean the log from the upstream server?

Comment: @xxfelixxx OMG !! it's working now ! I don't know how it fixed itself LOL

Comment: @tarun-lalwani  OMG !! it's working now ! I don't know how it fixed itself LOL

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42173/299217

Comment: Maybe all you needed to do was restart the server?

Comment: @xxfelixxx this is weird because I tried this before and it wasn't the solution, and now it's working .. I just don't understand what happened! thanks